# Potentiometers for vocal mics

Tags: resistors, audio, potentiometer

I want to mute the output of a wired headset mic so that when the power pack is turned on it doesn’t make a pop through the PA. I bought this little passive volume control, but with the volume fully CCW I still hear the pop (quieter, but it’s there).

I want to replace the 5K pot with a 50K, or even 100K. Will that solve my problem?

Note that this device will always be used either fully CW or fully CCW. Either full on, or full off.

[image]

Comment: I was not able to add the photo to my post. Here is a link to it. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/mtkfuo7qp3n3olw78ilmr/2023-09-12-22.13.18.jpg?rlkey=whprk76zcx70eu2sl7ozi53gj&dl=0

Comment: Photo added. . .

Comment: You need to trace out the circuit and draw a schematic to understand how it works. There's a CircuitLab schematic editor button on the edit toolbar. Drag and drop components on the page. R = rotate. H = flip horizontal. V = flip vertical. **Save and Insert** when done. No CircuitLab account needed.

Comment: Can we see a picture of the backside of that board?

Comment: I appreciate the advice, everyone is very kind.  Here is the back of the board.  Forgive me for not doing the circuitlab but the circuit is very elementary.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8h2myu6s7p276a30b9ysz/2023-09-13-14.48.40.jpg?rlkey=q1yjydbtgopmcriha9ebogugv&dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a dynamic mic, putting a pot in the path is really not a good idea. The mic has around 200 ohms output impedance and the mic preamp expects a direct connection.

If you want to mute a dynamic mic at source, the way to do it is to short circuit it - put a switch across it (but not good for condenser or electret types).

"When the power pack is turned on" - you mean it is a wireless mic? power pack of what? If this is your problem, this is not going to solve it.

Why don't you just turn down or mute the associated channel of the mixer while turning on power?

Comment: Thank you danmcb I should have asked a more complete question.  Our drummer has an old headset mic, condenser I think.  It is attached by wire to a battery pack.  This battery pack has a 3-pin XLR out to the mixer.

Our sound guy does mute the channel when the drummer is powering his mic on or off, but our drummer inevitably fiddles with the power pack and ends up making a loud pop through the PA.  I know there are mute switches out there but the economical ones are momentary and/or don't have a clear indication of whether the mic is currently live.

Comment: I bought the drummer and inexpensive gizmo a Rolls Music #ILC19 a little passive box with a volume control.  I thought, the drummer can turn it the whole way down before he fiddles with his mic.  We learned that this still enables a pop to come through the PA, albeit a much quieter one.  I opened the unit and saw a 5K pot and thought - if that was bigger, the volume would be quieter, maybe even nil.  So I thought about switching to a 100K pot but posted here because I don't know if it will actually work.  Presumably the current and new pots would both be 0 ohms when turned fully CW.

Comment: ahaha, I'm afraid we can discuss fixes to technical questions, but fixing drummers - the AI guys are still working on that ;-) seriously, using a larger pot won't help, the sound you still get is because the resistance is not zero with the vol at minimum. My advice - drill a hole, mount a simple latching toggle switch, wire it from wiper to ground, that will mute the mic completely when the switch is made.